# Pandas extracting values based on multiple columns

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I want to map values based on my columns called 'signed' and 'period' in pandas dataframe. My rules are based column 'period'

- if values contain months and quarters I want to return the dates they fall in
- if values contain winter or summer I also want to return the dates they fall in but summer is April and winter is October
- for everything else I want to return the date in column called 'signed'

I want to insert 4 new columns as per my output data

```
I have input data:

    period          signed
    May-20          16/05/2020
    August-20       10/05/2020
    Q2-20           14/05/2020
    Q3-20           21/05/2020
    10/05/2020      11/05/2020
    Summer 21       18/05/2020
    Winter 22       19/05/2020
    Weekend         20/05/2020
    week 15-20      21/05/2020
```

I want this output

```
    period          signed       day  month quarter year
    May-20          16/05/2020    1    5      2     2020
    August-20       10/05/2020    1    8      3     2020
    Q2-20           14/05/2020    1    4      2     2020
    Q3-21           21/05/2020    1    7      3     2021
    10/05/2020      11/05/2020    10   5      2     2020
    Summer 21       18/05/2020    1    4      2     2021
    Winter 22       19/05/2020    1    10     4     2022    
    Weekend         20/05/2020    20   5      2     2020
    week 15-20      21/05/2020    21   5      2     2020
```

This is the code I am trying to achieve that but it's only returning the values in 'signed' which doesn't follow my rules

```
      datemap = { 'January' :  {'day' : 1, 'month' : 1, 'quarter' : 1}, 
                    'February' : {'day' : 1, 'month' : 2, 'quarter' : 1}, 
                    'March' :    {'day' : 1, 'month' : 3, 'quarter' : 1}, 
                    # and so on ...
                    'Spring' : {'day' : 1, 'month' : 1, 'quarter' : 1}, 
                    'Summer' : {'day' : 1, 'month' : 4, 'quarter' : 2}, 
                    'Fall' :   {'day' : 1, 'month' : 7, 'quarter' : 3}, 
                    'Winter' : {'day' : 1, 'month' : 10, 'quarter' : 4}, 
                    'Q1' : {'day' : 1, 'month' : 1, 'quarter' : 1}, 
                    'Q2' : {'day' : 1, 'month' : 4, 'quarter' : 2}, 
                    'Q3' : {'day' : 1, 'month' : 7, 'quarter' : 3}, 
                    'Q4' : {'day' : 1, 'month' : 10, 'quarter' : 4}, 
                    'Year' : {'day' : 1, 'month' : 1, 'quarter' : 1} }

    import calendar

    def get_datemap_data(row,key,key_datemap):
        try:
            if key_datemap == "year":
                if key in datemap:
                    return row['period'].split()[1][-2:]
                else:
                    raise ValueError
            else:
                return datemap[key][key_datemap]
        except KeyError:
            signed_split = row["signed"].split("/")
            map_to_signed = {"day":0,"month":1}
            if key_datemap == "quarter":
                return datemap[calendar.month_name[int(signed_split[1])]]["quarter"]
            return int(signed_split[map_to_signed[key_datemap]])
        except ValueError:
            signed_split = row["signed"].split("/")
            return signed_split[2]


    df['day'] = df.apply (lambda r: get_datemap_data(r,r['period'].split()[0],'day'), axis=1)
    df['month'] = df.apply (lambda r: get_datemap_data(r,r['period'].split()[0],'month'), axis=1)
    df['quarter'] = df.apply (lambda r: get_datemap_data(r,r['period'].split()[0],'quarter'), axis=1)
    df['year'] = df.apply (lambda r: "20" + get_datemap_data(r,r['period'].split()[0],'year'), axis=1)
```

Comment: 1. `datemap` doesn't have keys like `10/05/2020` and you handle key errors by using the `signed` column which has the value `11/05/2020`.
2. `r['period'].split()[0]` works only on values containing a space, if you change `May-20` to `May 20` it will work.
3. `lambda r: "20" +...` the `"20" + ` is relevant only for some rows, insert it in the correct place in your function rather than adding it to every result.
Try to debug your code and see where it fails, your mistakes are minor but they are not few. Hint: if it returns the `signed` values you're probably getting `ValueError`s.

Comment: Thanks. 2. ```r['period'].split()[0]``` fixed my problem.